# curl/curl.h missing from Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

I'm trying to understand how to run http commands in C++ so I can send requests to an API online and receive a Json response. However, I can't even begin to understand how this works, or what to do. I know I have curl installed on my PC (Windows 10), I checked, and it's there. But... I don't understand how to connect that to Visual Studio? I see a lot of people writing code with

```
#Include <"curl/curl.h">
```

I have no idea where this library exists on my PC, where to find it, how to integrate it, etc. Can anyone please help me?

I also see a lot of people using bash? But that's a linux thing, I don't have Linux and have no idea how it works. I'd appreciate just a basic explanation of how to get curl to work with cpp, because I've scoured the internet relentlessly, curlpp doesn't work, libcurl requires tools I don't have and don't fathom, and frankly... It feels like a nightmare of complication for something that should be, on surface level, relatively simple?

Thank you in advance for anyone who could take the time to help me with this.

Comment: You have to tell VS where to look... also, the code snippet you posted isn't valid C++

Comment: curl is just a cli-tool. you should be able to use it with the windows command line exactly like bash.

Comment: Also, it's `#include`, with a lowercase 'I'. There's a lot to unwrap in this question. You need to have one question. People can talk about installing libraries, activating WSL (that should have been easily searchable, though), configuring VS, etc.

Comment: If you don't want to use libcurl, you can also use [WinHTTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/about-winhttp) or [WhenINet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wininet/portal) when you are using Microsoft Windows. However, that means that your code will be limited to Microsoft Windows and won't run on other platforms, such as Linux.

Comment: The name `curl` refers to the command-line utility, which can be called from `bash` on Linux or `cmd.exe` on Microsoft Windows. The name of the library used by `curl` is called `libcurl`, which you can use yourself in your C++ programs. Although it is possible to call `curl` directly from your C++ programs, it is usually recommended that you use `libcurl` instead. The program `curl` is intended to be called directly by the user or from bash scripts.